# MySQLdb Register program?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

So me and a friend are trying to learn MySQLdb together and we're starting with a register program. Here's the code right now:

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import time

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",port=3306,user="root",passwd="",db="testing" )
cur = db.cursor()

def register():
    print "Welcome to user registration!"
    user = raw_input("Username: ")
    passw = raw_input("Password: ")
    confpass = raw_input("Confirm password: ")
    if confpass.lower() != passw.lower():
        print "Passwords do not match!"
        register()
    print "Almost done!"
    email = raw_input("E-mail: ")
    confemail = raw_input("Confirm E-mail: ")
    if email.lower() != confemail.lower():
        print "Emails do not match!"
        register()
    add_user = ("INSERT INTO testing1 "
                "username, password"
                "VALUES (%s, %s)")

    data_test = (user, passw)
    cur.execute(add_user, data_test)
    db.close()

choice = raw_input("Do you want to register or login?: ")
if choice.lower() == 'register':
    register()

db.close()
```

I've looked at some docs but I don't get what's missing.
My database is called testing, the table is called testing1, and there's just the username (varchar 25) and password (text) values. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MySQLTesting.py", line 54, in <module>
    register()
  File "MySQLTesting.py", line 33, in register
    cur.execute(add_user, data_test)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.0\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202,
 in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Panda3D-1.8.0\python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line
36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax
; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right s
yntax to use near 'username, passwordVALUES ('Thing', 'idk')' at line 1")
```

Comment: From the error message, I would guess you need a space after `"username, password`.

Comment: ... or before VALUES

Comment: That's not it, I tried both and it gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) you should wrap your column names in parentheses :

```
add_user = "INSERT INTO testing1 (username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```